# Determine if a field is a system field

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I would like to know if there is a clever/short way to determine if a field in a table is generated from the system. I only have the TableNum and the FieldNum as variables (nothing hard coded, only dynamic values) and I'd like to be able to write something like this (pseudo-code):

```
if( Sys::isSystemField(tableId, fieldId) )
{
    //...
}
```

Instead of:

```
//...
str fieldName;
//...
;
//...

fieldName = dictTable.fieldName(fieldId);

if(fieldName == "modifiedDateTime"
    || fieldName == "DEL_ModifiedTime"
    || fieldName == "modifiedBy"
    || //etc...)
{

//...
```

Which is what I'll be writing if there is no way to do what I'm looking for. Hopefully someone can help, I haven't find anything about that in the documentation unfortunately.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `isSysId` a global method.

It is for example used in `Global::buf2buf`:

```
static void buf2Buf(Common _from, Common  _to)
{
    DictTable   dictTable = new DictTable(_from.TableId);
    fieldId     fieldId   = dictTable.fieldNext(0);
    while (fieldId && ! isSysId(fieldId))
    {
        _to.(fieldId)   = _from.(fieldId);
        fieldId         = dictTable.fieldNext(fieldId);
    }
}
```